# What is Z3Py FreshBool() function?

Tags: syntax, z3, z3py, sat, sat-solvers

What is the difference between z3.Bool() and z3.FreshBool() functions?
My code in z3 on python fails when I use Bool() (the solver returns unsat when it shouldn't), but works fine when I use FreshBool() (Desired behaviour is observed).

I cannot give out details of the code here, as it is part of an ongoing assignment in a course offered in my college.
Even still, if this information isn't sufficient, I can try and recreate in an unrelated code, to provide you with a better sample to work on.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `FreshBool()` then z3 will create a new variable that does not exist elsewhere in the system. When you use `Bool` and give it a name, then it will be the same variable if created elsewhere.

To wit, consider:

```py
from z3 import *

# These two are *different* variables even though they have the same name
a = FreshBool("a")
b = FreshBool("a")

s = Solver();

s.add(a != b)
print(s.check())
```

This will print:

```
sat
```

since the variables are different. (And hence can have different values in the model.)

But if you try:

```py
from z3 import *

# These two are the *same* variable, since they have the same name
a = Bool("a")
b = Bool("a")

s = Solver();

s.add(a != b)
print(s.check())
```

Then you'll get:

```
unsat
```

because `a` and `b` are the same variable since they have the same name.

Most end-user code should simply use `Bool`, since this is the usual intended semantics: You refer to different variables with their names when you created them. But when developing libraries, you might want to create a temporary variable that is not the same as any other variable in the system. In these cases, you use `FreshBool`. Note that in this latter case the string you provide is used as a prefix. If you add `print(get_model())` at the end of the first program, it'll print:

```
sat
[a!0 = True, a!1 = False]
```

showing the internally created "fresh" names.

z3 also provides similar functions for other types too, such as `Int()` vs `FreshInt()`, `Real()` vs `FreshReal()` etc.; intended to be used in exactly the same manner.